Transactional annotation is not working in pure Spring with EntitManager
I have a simple bookdao class:
@Repository
public class BookDao {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void create(Book book) {
        entityManager.persist(book);
  }

}


I have a main method, where I try to save a new book into the database:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);

        BookDao bookDao = context.getBean(BookDao.class);

        Book book = new Book("Sample Book");

        bookDao.create(book);
    }
}

And finally my spring config:
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setPersistenceUnitName("persistence");
        emf.afterPropertiesSet();
        return emf.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public BookDao bookDao() {
        return new BookDao();
    }

    @Bean
    public BookService bookService() {
        return new BookService();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
        ds.setUsername("user");
        ds.setPassword("password");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}

In BookDao class, if I remove the entityManager.getTransaction.begin() code, the new book is not added to the databse.
Help me please, I try to solve this issue for two days. As I know, transactional does not work, if the method is private, or it is called from the same class. But this is not the case here.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You shouldn't use entityManager.getTransaction().begin() and entityManager.getTransaction().commit() in @Transactional method, @Transactional annotation is enough for transaction.

I know it, this is the reason, why entityManager.getTransaction().begin() and entityManager.getTransaction().commit() lines are commented!

So why for do you need this lines?

I was able to solve it! I needed to change Autowired to PersistenceContext above EntityManager.
